# EF database / model first unit (integration) tests

Tags: database, entity-framework, unit-testing, integration-testing, ef-database-first

I want each of my unit (integration) test methods to use a clean and consistent database and specific test data for each test.

Could you please provide me some code samples/snippets and tell me what are best practices for the following questions for both scenarios EF 5 database first and model first.

1. How to create the database for each test method?
2. How to set up the test data for each test method?
3. How to delete the database for each test method?
4. SSDT project is used to handle database schema, how to use the current SSDT schema for each test run? So that the tests are always executed against the current development version of the database.

Please consider the following assumptions for above questions:

1. The unit tests shall be executed locally on dev machine and on server CI builds.
2. Each test may have different test data.
3. Manually defined .mdf test files should be avoided because several developers are working on the product and there is a potential risk that one deleoper overwrites the changes of the .mdf file which another developer may have checked in previously -> development process should be as simpel as possible.
4. SSDT is used, so maybe this an option to create the database (probably not a good one because I want the database to be created for each test) and I have no deep knowledge yet about SSDT possiblities.
5. A good performance of test execution time would be nice to have.
6. VS/TFS 2012 is used.
7. SQL Server 2012 is used.
8. Application is a C# desktop application.
9. Mocking EF context etc. is not an option.

I hope you can guide me into the right direction how to solve the 4 questions from above. I don´t know if EF provides some functionality (I think only for code first) for my challenges or if this all must be solved by executing SQL scripts or something like that.

Thanks!

Comment: Wow.  2 years and no answer for this question.  Surely someone has got some ideas by now!?